# Open Android app via scheme without using url

Tags: android, html

I have an android scheme name: android.scheme and I want to open the android app when i click on:

```
android.scheme://serversettings?personalizationhost=192.168.32.122&personalizationport=8080&vpnhost=192.168.32.122
```

How I can do that any help?

I know how I can achieve the same using but putting this in an HTML page and opening that page will open the app like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "android.scheme://serversettings?personalizationhost=192.168.32.122&personalizationport=8080&vpnhost=192.168.32.122"</script>
        <title>AuthenticVPN Settings</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I don't want to click on url and then open the app. I want to click on android.scheme directly which opens the app.
Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: "But I don't want to click on url and then open the app. I want to click on android.scheme directly which opens the app." -- that makes no sense to me, sorry. The scheme is part of the URL. And the user clicks on *neither* the URL nor the scheme, as those are part of HTML source code. The user clicks on a hyperlink, or something tied to a snippet of JavaScript.

Comment: You mean thats not possible at all? All right then I have to go ahead with url only.

Comment: "You mean thats not possible at all?" -- since I do not know what you are trying to do, I cannot answer that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a separate page that redirects to the URI with android.scheme scheme. You can create a link on the original page using the same scheme. Something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    You can <a href="android.scheme://serversettings?personalizationhost=192.168.32.122&personalizationport=8080&vpnhost=192.168.32.122">launch Activity</a> directly with anchor tags.
  </body>
</html>
```

And add an intent filter for the launched intent to your Activity:

```
<intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="android.scheme"/>
  <data android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

You can even use the same scheme to launch different activities by using differents hosts for the data filter and corresponding URL:

```
<data android:scheme="android.scheme" android:host="serversettings" />
```

or

```
<data android:scheme="android.scheme" android:host="clientstatus" />
```

Comment: thnx for your answer. the problem is the fields personalizationhost and others in the url I have to generate the value for them dynamically and then sent the url. I don't understand how I can do that